# How to target text widget?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a text widget which I want to target to turn text into one line.How? div class doesn't seem to respond or my css is wrong.

```css
.textwidget {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
  <h2 class="widget-title">More</h2>
  <div class="textwidget">
    <p>© Adsler 2019-2039 All rights reserved.<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/terms-and-conditions/">Terms and 
Conditions</a><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/cookie-policy/">Cookie 
Policy</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i edited your question making a snippet with your code. Can you be more clear about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: The text links are stacked on top of each other. Want ©Adsler..... Plus text links all on one line. Page: https://adsler.co.uk

Comment: its already on one line, what you want to achieve finally?

Comment: @charankumar is it in mobile view? Not in desktop chrome either as far as i can see? The links and text are on separate lines

Comment: well if they don't 'fit' on one line. What would your desired result be like ?

Comment: Well over two lines then please...

Comment: Text align left over two lines...

Comment: :) That's what's happening now. If they don't fit on one line, it goes on two lines. If they don't fit on two lines, it goes on three lines. How exactly do you want the diferent elements to behave. For eg on line 1 : `©Adsler 2019-2039` ; second line : `All rights reserved.` , third line : links. And so on :)

Comment: There's definitely enough space for two lines of text? Maximum three? Just so it runs concurrently, if that makes sense?

Comment: ©Adlser All right reserved. 2019-2039 Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, Terms and Conditions.......

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screencapture]

The sentence is already all on one line.

Comment: The code on your site is not the same as the code you've posted in your question. 

In the code on your site each of the items are contained within `<p>` tags which will be dropping them below each other. 

Also, the space that you have available looks too small to hold them all on one line, even if they were.